# logistic regression graph - understanding data

Tags: logistic-regression

I am trying to understand why my data is not showing a full S-curve? Is it because the predictor does not do a good job of predicting fellow = 1, or simply because there are few fellow = 1 that score within the top end on c_ns2 (x-axis variable)?

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

///

when attempting to extend x-xis to range from 2.5--7: [image]

```
##### 2 #####
ggplot(graph_df, aes(c_ns2, fellow)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = 'glm', method.args = list(family = "binomial"), se = FALSE, size = 2, colour = "lightblue") +
  theme_classic() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5, colour = "grey50", linetype = 2, size = 1) +
    xlim(c(2.5, 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend your graph out for larger c_ns2 (x-axis). The graph will then show a full sigmoid curve. There are likely many more fellow=0 than fellow=1 and the relative distribution weights the fitted curve quite heavily towards them.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation @njp. There is an upper limit to the x-axis variable: 5.32, so can I ask what you mean by extending the c-axis? 

This is exactly right! There are many more 0s than 1s in the true data. 

I found it a little interesting that when plotting the predicted probabilities (instead of fitting the data with a glm, binomial function), it extends a little more (added above).

Comment: Not sure what graphics package you are plotting this in, but just set the x limits of the figure to, say, [2.5, 7]. It looks like the centre of the curve is around 4.75. Your predictions (bottom panel) will look the same but hopefully the blue curve will show the full sigmoid curve that you are after.

Comment: thanks! I have extended the breaks on the x-axis (in R), and still thefitted line isn't extending much above 0.5 (see new pic) with added code!

Comment: try `+ xlim(c(2.5, 7))` rather than `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(2.5, 7.0, 0.5))`

Comment: thanks--the data ends, but line extends

Comment: Maybe try `fullrange=T` in the `geom_smooth` layer also noting this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66959036/why-is-fullrange-true-not-working-for-geom-smooth-in-ggplot2

Comment: Thanks! this worked! is the full range = TRUE basically predicting the rest of the curve regardless of data?